# How to write own browser for the Android, without re-inventing the wheel?

Tags: javascript, android, html, browser

I really don't want to write an entire browser from scratch but the [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5266510/standalone-javascript-layout-engine) I received so far, regarding the ability to access rendered Javascript OUTPUT in existing WebView, lead me to believe that this is the ONLY way for me to accomplish that.

How do I write my own NON-VISUAL web browser for the Android, without re-inventing the wheel?

Comment: Isn't asking "how do I write something without reinventing" like saying "how do I walk without taking steps"?

Comment: Heh... question title on its own sounds like "How do I invent something which rolls in order to make things run smoothly without reinventing the wheel?", but I understand that's not what you mean. Just thought it sounded funny.

Comment: You were given a solution to your original problem. Use it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376471/how-do-i-get-the-web-page-contents-from-a-web-view/4892013#4892013

Answer (score 1):

Having never developed for Android, I'm afraid I'd be of limited help, so take this with a grain of salt.

I see three options, the hard way writing from scratch (re-inventing the wheel)

A second option which combines existing tools with a minimal wrapper written by yourself, for which the basic components you would need are:

- A DOM Parser
- JavaScript engine (e.g. V8)
- wget

The last option would be to go the way of [NVDA](http://www.nvda-project.org/). And it might be worth working with them directly on something like this.

I'm not familiar enough with the inner-workings of NVDA to speak on their methods specifically, however it is a rather successful project and a working model of what your trying to do, albeit on a different platform.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I write my own NON-VISUAL web browser for the Android, without re-inventing the wheel?

Screen readers for Windows computers, like [Jaws](http://www.freedomscientific.com/products/fs/jaws-product-page.asp), rely on what the browser shows them.